# how to create sequence

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2003

I am exporting file from MS Access table to my local, I am doing this VBA coding.
I need to create Sequence for the file names in such a manner,

```
File1PN00001
File1PN00002
File1PN00003
...

...
```

I am doing this by following code

```
Private Sub Command0_Click()
Dim FileName As String
Dim intChoice As Integer
Dim strPath As String
Dim LSProc As QueryDef
Dim db As Database
Set db = CurrentDb()

Set LSProc = db.CreateQueryDef("")

'make the file dialog visible to the user
strFilePath = BrowseFolder("Please Select Path to Export Neutrality Report file to")

If strFilePath <> "" Then
Call MsgBox(strFilePath, vbInformation, "Save Path")
Else
 MsgBox "Please Provide a file path before exporting!", vbCritical + vbOKOnly
End If
 FileName = strFilePath & "File1PN" & Format(txtBal_Number, "000000") & ".txt"

  DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, , "T1", FileName, False
End Sub
```

I am confused how to create sequence for that, how to create sequence and how to increase the value by 1 every time when this code runs. Could you please help me out with this 
Thanks.

Comment: Do you wish to export all tables in the DB to txt file?

Comment: Well, you need to find the numbers of the last saved files in that directory. Grab the numeric part and increase by 1 when saving?

Comment: @PaulFrancis : No, not all tables only those tables which are required. Here T1 is the table which is exporting

Comment: @vba4all: could you do that thing in this coding. Thanks

Comment: @ravichaudhary, it is possible with a logging system. It might be a bit of coding. Create a log table, every time an export happens it needs to create a record. Then the next time it has to look for the maximum number in this log and use that. I will see if I can write a detailed explanation. Email me (check my profile for my id) !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get this sorted if you have a logging system. First you need to create a table nothing fancy, just a simple table with two columns.

```
tbl_FileNameLog
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
FIELD NAME  |   DATA TYPE   |                   COMMENTS
------------+---------------+---------------------------------------------
fileID      |   Number      |   Could use Auto Number, but for future safe.
            |               |       use Number, so you can edit it.
            |               |       But make sure it is a Primary Key.
exportDate  |   Date/Time   |   Just a Date field to store the Date.
```

Now you can edit your code to something like.

```
Private Sub Command0_Click()
    Dim strPath As String, FileName As String
    Dim lngChoice As Long
    Dim dbObj As Database

    Set dbObj = CurrentDb()

    'make the file dialog visible to the user
    strFilePath = BrowseFolder("Please Select Path to Export Neutrality Report file to")

    If strFilePath <> "" Then
        MsgBox "Exporting File to : " & strFilePath, vbInformation, "Save Path"
    Else
        MsgBox "Please Provide a file path before exporting!", vbCritical + vbOKOnly
        Exit Sub
    End If

    lngChoice = Nz(DMax("fileID", "tbl_FileNameLog"), 0) + 1

    FileName = strFilePath & "File1PN" & Format(lngChoice, "000000") & ".txt"

    DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, , "T1", FileName, False

    dbObj.Execute "INSERT INTO tbl_FileNameLog (fileID, exportDate) VALUES (" & _
                  lngChoice & ", " & CDbl(Date()) & ")"

    Set dbObj = Nothing
End Sub
```

So the first time when the code is run, it will look for the Max ID in the table. Since there is no entry it will make use of the Nz function and assign a 0+1, so an ID of 1 is obtained. Then Export happens to the specified location. At the same time an entry into the file log is put stating the ID has been assigned. So the next time when the code runs, it will look for the file log table since ID of 1 is availabe it will not use 2. So on and so forth....

This way it does not rely upon the file system. It has its own log, so even if the file is moved or deleted it will still be able to provide a consistent/continious numbering. Hope this helps !

Comment: Glad you have it sorted ! Good luck. :)